# Use the Date as a criteria in Dsum function, access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have to generate a rolling sum or Cumulative sum of the OIL field for each WELLNMBR as per its MONTH value.

The query used is

```
{SELECT tblProductionData.WELLNMBR, tblProductionData.[Month], tblProductionData.DAYS, tblProductionData.OIL, tblProductionData.GAS, tblProductionData.WATER, DSum("[OIL]","tblProductionData","WELLNMBR=" & "'" & [WELLNMBR] & "'" & "AND MONTH <=" & "#" & [MONTH] & "#") AS Expr2
FROM tblProductionData;
```

In the result the sum changes after every year, not after a month. I would like to know the reason for this strange behavior and the method to obtain the rolling sum in every month.

Incorrect result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFBRm.png

Desired result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8I9r.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query begins '{'. This needs to be removed. Also 'MONTH' is a reserved word. Try replacing it with 'Mth', then proceed from there.